# How can I run REST from batch or powershell?

Tags: 2013, powershell, rest, sql

I want to create an item (Title,ID, description) in Mylist by using REST/batch/powershell/SQL store procedure
Any reference or information will be appreciated.

Comment: In sharepoint 2013

Comment: I know something like this. But I don't know how to call it:
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘Test')/items
method: POST
body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestListItem' }, 'Title': 'Test'}
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
     X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-length:length of post body

Comment: The goal is create an item in a list from SQL server/Store Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done that before but with a little googling I found something for you:
http://www.lavinski.me/calling-a-rest-json-api-with-powershell/

This works so far with Powershell:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "your REST URL" -UseDefaultCredentials
```

otherwise you would need to specify your credentials directly.

Answer (score 0):

Rest API Create item:

```
    // occurs when a user clicks the create button
function CreateNew() {
    var listName = "MyList";
    var newItemTitle = "New Title Item";
    CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, newItemTitle, function () {
        alert("New Item has been created successfully.");
 }, function () {
     alert("Ooops, an error occured. Please try again.");
 });
}

// CREATE Operation
// listName: The name of the list you want to get items from
// weburl: The url of the web that the list is in. 
// newItemTitle: New Item title.
// success: The function to execute if the call is sucesfull
// failure: The function to execute if the call fails
function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, newItemTitle, success, failure) {
    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": itemType },
        "Title": newItemTitle
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}

// Get List Item Type metadata
function GetItemTypeForListName(name) {
    return "SP.Data." + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.split(" ").join("").slice(1) + "ListItem";
}
```

Reference:

[Rest CRUD action on List Item](https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/create-retrieve-update-and-delete-sharepoint-list-item-using-rest-api-and-jquery/)

PowerShell script create item:

```
$weburl = "http://mysharepoint"
$listname = "TestList"
$a = "Text1"
$b = "Text2"
$c = "Text3"

Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction silentlycontinue  
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $webUrl
$list = $web.Lists[$listname]
$newItem = $list.items.add()
$newitem["Title"] = $a
$newitem["Custom_Column1"] = $b
$newitem["Custom_Column2"] = $c
$newitem.update()
```